# Modify value in directive's scope from separate directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Let's say I have a chart directive (like a pie chart) and a settings directive that contains a form used to modify the settings for the chart directive. The settings directive is displayed in a modal dialogue.

**How can I make it so that changes in the settings directive take effect in the chart directive?**

There can be multiple chart directives, each with independent settings. The settings for each chart will actually be shown as tabs in the settings modal, but I left that out to keep the example simple.

Here are some things I have tried/considered:

"Use a factory to share the Settings values." This fails because I might have multiple chart directives, each with separate settings.

"Have the settings directive be a child of the chart directive." The settings directive cannot be a child of the chart directive because it needs to be rendered in the modal.

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nqGwJth7y0b32lUkyKkf?p=preview) along w/ some relevant snippets:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <a href ng-click="showSettings()">Settings</a>
    <chart></chart>
    <chart></chart>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("Controller", function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.showSettings = function () {
        $modal.open({
                    scope: $scope,
                    template: "<h1>Settings Modal</h1><settings></settings>"
                }
        );
    }
});

app.directive("chart", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>Chart Directive</h1><p>someChartSetting: {{someChartSetting}}</p>',
        controller: function ChartController($scope) {
            // This value represents a setting that I need to modify via the settings modal.
            $scope.someChartSetting = "on";
        }
    }
})

app.directive("settings", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a href ng-click="toggleSettings()">Toggle someChartSetting</a>',
        controller: function SettingsController($scope) {
            $scope.toggleSettings = function () {
                console.log("Toggle clicked");
                // This is where I need to modify the someChartSetting value from chart.
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you not give each chart a unique ID, and then store the settings in a factory inside of an associative array/object, where the key matches the chart ID? So where you declare the chart, use <chart id="abc123"></chart>

Comment: I could. I did consider that, but it feels a little hackish. These directives are semi-scattered across a larger application framework, so keeping track of IDs could be annoying. I was hoping for a way to directly connect the settings directive with the chart directive. What you suggest would work though.

Comment: Without an ID, that suggests the settings need to be kept internally in the Chart instance itself. Perhaps it might be worth building a BaseModal directive, and then have a ChartSettingsModal that derived from BaseModal. Assuming the button for triggering the visibility of the modal exists inside the Chart directive, you could then call the show method of the ChartSettingsModal controller (through require property) which contains all the relevant settings.

Comment: The settings are kept in the chart directive. The button for triggering the settings modal is not inside the chart directive, it is outside. The use case is: multiple charts w/ a single settings modal, and tabs within that setting modal - 1 tab per chart instance.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <a href ng-click="showSettings()">Settings</a>
    <chart></chart>
    <chart></chart>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller("Controller", function ($scope, $modal) {
        $scope.showSettings = function () {
            $modal.open({
                        scope: $scope,
                        template: "<h1>Settings Modal</h1><settings></settings>"
                    }
            );
        }
    });

    app.directive("chart", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<h1>Chart Directive</h1><p>someChartSetting: {{someChartSetting}}</p>',
            controller: function ChartController($scope) {
                // This value represents a setting that I need to modify via the settings modal.
                $scope.someChartSetting = "on";
            }
        }
    })

    app.directive("settings", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<a href ng-click="toggleSettings()">Toggle someChartSetting</a>',
            controller: function SettingsController($scope) {
                $scope.toggleSettings = function () {
                    // This is where I need to modify the someChartSetting value from chart.
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/g0oGMzlsGYaSkumh4aho?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see that you moved the setting into the parent controller and so that it could be passed to the chart and settings directive. Not a bad idea, but I am hoping to keep as much of the chart directive implementation out of the parent controller as possible. If this is not doable then I might have to go w/ what you have.